# Ruby gem can not be located event it shows, that gem installed

Tags: ruby, macos, terminal, rubygems, fastlane

What is the way to fix, that **fastlane snapshot update** will locate **aws-partitions-1.445.0**?

For some reasons *aws-partitions-1.445.0* gem can not be found:

```
rj@MBP app % bundle exec fastlane snapshot update
Could not find aws-partitions-1.445.0 in any of the sources
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
```

But it shows info, that aws-partitions installed on my Mac:

```
rj@MBP app % bundle info aws-partitions        
  * aws-partitions (1.445.0)
    Summary: Provides information about AWS partitions, regions, and services.
    Homepage: https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ruby
    Source Code: https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ruby/tree/version-3/gems/aws-partitions
    Changelog: https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ruby/tree/version-3/gems/aws-partitions/CHANGELOG.md
    Path: /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/aws-partitions-1.445.0
```